# C#, finding the largest prime factor of a number

Tags: c#

I am new at programming and I am practicing my C# programming skills. My application is meant to find the largest prime factor of a number entered by the user. But my application is not returning the right answer and I dont really know where the problem is. Can you please help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calcular máximo factor primo de n. De 60 es 5.");
            Console.Write("Escriba un numero: ");
            long num = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
            long mfp = maxfactor(num);
            Console.WriteLine("El maximo factor primo es: " + num);
            Console.Read();
        }
        static private long maxfactor (long n)
        {
            long m=1 ;
            bool en= false;
            for (long k = n / 2; !en && k > 1; k--)
            {
                if (n % k == 0 && primo(k))
                {
                    m = k;
                    en = true;
                }
            }
            return m;

        }
        static private bool primo(long x)
        {
            bool sp = true;
            for (long i = 2; i <= x / 2; i++)
            {
                if (x % i == 0)
                    sp = false;
            }
            return sp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you this person or their classmate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505433/wrong-answer-on-c-application-finding-the-n-prime-of-a-list-of-prime-numbers/2505458#2505458

Comment: A single person having more than one SO account is frowned upon.

Comment: trying Project Euler #3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will be much faster to remove the small factors until the residue is prime.

```
static private long maxfactor (long n)
{
    long k = 2;
    while (k * k <= n)
    {
        if (n % k == 0)
        {
            n /= k;
        }
        else
        {
            ++k;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

For example, if n = 784, this does 9 modulo operations instead of several hundred.  Counting down even with the sqrt limit still would do 21 modulo ops just in maxfactor, and another dozen in primo.

New more optimized version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951936/largest-prime-factor-algorithm-optimization/4952013#4952013)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but if you're still there, can you explain the concept that led to this algorithm or point me in the right direction to read more on this?

Comment: @eric_s: What part are you unclear about?  Usage of `%` to find remainder?  Usage of remainder to identify factors?  The reason for checking for small factors first?

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine("El maximo factor primo es: " + mfp);
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("El maximo factor primo es: " + num);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have condition (!en) that makes it iterate only until first prime factor. Also you can reduce bounds from n/2 to sqrt(n)+1

Comment: He only wants it to find the maximum prime factor, so the `en` condition should be fine, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Catalin DICU already answered your question, but you've got some non-idiomatic constructs in your code that you should probably look at refactoring. For example, in your `maxfactor` method, you don't need the "en" condition, just return the value as soon as you've found it:

```
static private long maxfactor (long n)
{
    for (long k = n / 2; k > 1; k--)
    {
        if (n % k == 0 && primo(k))
        {
            return k;
        }
    }

    // no factors found
    return 1;
}
```

Similarly for your `primo` method, you can just return `false` as soon as you find a factor.

Answer (score 0):

here's a f# version for this:

```
let lpf n =
    let rec loop n = function        
        |k when k*k >= n -> n
        |k when n % k = 0I -> loop (n/k) k
        |k -> loop n (k+1I)
    loop n 2I
```

Answer (score -1):

This runs for less than three seconds.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int prime=1;    
    long n=600851475143;
     for (long i=2;i<=n;i++)
      {
       while (n%i==0)
         n=n/i;
         prime++;
      }
    Console.WriteLine(prime);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: This adds no value as it is a slightly worse method than Ben Voigt's answer.