# Largest Prime Factor algorithm optimization

Tags: c#, prime-factoring

I'm trying to improve this interesting algorithm as much as I can.

For now, I have this:

```
using System;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        ulong num, largest_pFact;
        uint i = 2;
        string strNum;

        Console.Write("Enter number: ");
        strNum = Console.ReadLine();
        num = ulong.Parse(strNum);
        largest_pFact = num;


        while (i < Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact))
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0 | i == 2) {
                if (largest_pFact % i == 0) 
                    largest_pFact /= i;
            }

            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Largest prime factor of {0} is: {1}", num, largest_pFact);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

So any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I implemented Ben's algorithm, thanks eveyone for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, finding the largest prime factor of a number ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535251/c-finding-the-largest-prime-factor-of-a-number)

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong.  What is the largest prime factor of 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a faster algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535251/c-finding-the-largest-prime-factor-of-a-number/2535285#2535285).

It eliminates the square root and handles repeated factors correctly.

Optimizing further:

```
static private ulong maxfactor (ulong n)
{
    unchecked
    {
        while (n > 3 && 0 == (n & 1)) n >>= 1;

        uint k = 3;
        ulong k2 = 9;
        ulong delta = 16;
        while (k2 <= n)
        {
            if (n % k == 0)
            {
                n /= k;
            }
            else
            {
                k += 2;
                if (k2 + delta < delta) return n;
                k2 += delta;
                delta += 8;
            }
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Here's a working demo: http://ideone.com/SIcIL

Comment: @Vlad: Improved even more (eliminated multiply).

Comment: Seems so but i get a lot of errors with the last update (because of unchecked) and the first.

Comment: @Vlad: typo fixed, sorry about that

Comment: It works now and is much faster than my "incomplete algorithm", thanks Ben. ;) (on my algorithm for a 20 digit number the search took about 30 min and now it gets the result in less than 3 sec it's really incredible)

Comment: @Vlad: Careful, only some 20 digit numbers fit in a `ulong`... And if it was prime, your algorithm could have overflowed `i` and never finished.  That's what that really weird `if (k2 + delta < delta)` is there to catch.

Comment: @Ben: Well then i guess I have to make some bounds checking before parsing the string. ;)

Comment: @Ben: One question: Why is k an uint while k an ulong?

Comment: @Vlad: `k` is equivalent to your `i`, it only goes up to the square-root of `n`, so it only needs half as many bits as `n`.  `k2` is always `k*k`, and needs to get as big as `n`, but we don't calculate it directly because multiplication is slower than addition.  Expand `knew*knew` = `(kold+2)*(kold+2)` = `kold*kold + 4*kold + 4`.  Call `kold*kold` k2 and `4*kold+4` delta and you get this code.

Comment: On my box it becomes faster with: "k += 2; k2 += delta; if (k2 < delta) return n; delta += 8". Eliminate square roots? If a number has x different prime factors, no more than x square roots are needed,
see:[numericana](http://www.numericana.com/answer/factoring.htm#trial)

Comment: @P_P: Ok, your first change makes sense (although the compiler should have done that -- did you compile with optimization?)  For the second, sure `x` square roots is an improvement over `sqrt(n)` square roots, but zero is even better.

Comment: @Ben: Optimize code? Yes. My solution can be found at Project Euler, but will probably disappear soon.

Answer (score 1):

-Store Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact) in some variable, preferably a ulong. That avoids recalculating the function every pass through the loop, and integer comparison may be faster than floating-point comparisons. You will need to change the comparison to a <= though.

-Avoid looping on even numbers at all. Just include a special case for i=2, and then start with i at 3, incrementing by 2 on each loop. You can go even further by letting i=2,3 be special cases, and then only testing i = 6n+1 or 6n-1.

Comment: But the square root changes whenever a factor is found... of course the square root isn't necessary at all.

Comment: At which point you update the number- the number of extra calculations will be very small. Though I was just trying to improve his algorithm incremently rather than decisively.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first I would move the special case 2 out of the loop, there is no point in checking for that throughout the loop when it can be handled once. If possible use the data type `int` rather than `uint`, as it's generally faster:

```
if (largest_pFact % 2 == 0) {
  largest_pFact /= 2;
}
int i = 3;
while (i < Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact)) {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    if (largest_pFact % i == 0) {
      largest_pFact /= i;
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

The square root calculation is relatively expensive, so that should also be done beforehand:

```
if (largest_pFact % 2 == 0) {
  largest_pFact /= 2;
}
int i = 3;
int sq = Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact);
while (i < sq) {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    if (largest_pFact % i == 0) {
      largest_pFact /= i;
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

Then I would increment `i` in steps of two, to elliminate one modulo check:

```
if (largest_pFact % 2 == 0) {
  largest_pFact /= 2;
}
int i = 3;
int sq = Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact);
while (i < sq) {
  if (largest_pFact % i == 0) {
    largest_pFact /= i;
  }
  i += 2;
}
```

To work, I believe that you need a `while` instead of an `if` inside the loop, otherwise it will skip factors that are repeated:

```
if (largest_pFact % 2 == 0) {
  largest_pFact /= 2;
}
int i = 3;
int sq = Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact);
while (i < sq) {
  while (largest_pFact % i == 0) {
    largest_pFact /= i;
  }
  i += 2;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but about the sqrt outside the loop may not be faster because inside it makes the search smaller by each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you don't need to run `Math.Sqrt` on every iteration.

```
    int root = Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact);

    while (i < root)
    {
        if ((i % 2 != 0 | i == 2) && largest_pFact % i == 0) {
            largest_pFact /= i;
            root = Math.Sqrt((double) largest_pFact);
        }

        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

- generate primes up to `num`/2
- then check from largest to lowest if your `num` is divisible by the prime

would be faster.

edit num/2 NOT sqrt

Comment: That might work for smaller numbers but for huge numbers would take too much.

Answer (score 0):

It's always faster to look between sqrt(num) and 2 than it is to start at num/2. Every factor pair (besides the square-root one) has one number that is less than sqrt(num).

Ex: For 15, int(sqrt(15))==3
    15/3=5, so you found the "5" factor by starting your testing at 3 instead of 7.

Comment: This is meant as a comment on damienix's answer?  Hurry up and get some rep so you can leave comments the right way ;)